# Load source HTML as string using CefSharp Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to use the CefSharp WPF package to load a web page then access the HTML source of the web page I have loaded.

I am able to display the web page correctly, but I want to be able to see the HTML of the page.

I am able to call the following, but it displays the text in a temporary text file, however I want to see the source as a string ideally but would be ok if the file saved to disk.

```
_webBrowser.ViewSourceCommand.Execute(this);
```

This is my class

```
public partial class View: Window
{
    private CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser _webBrowser; 
    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.PackLoadingDisabled = true;
        _webBrowser = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser();
        BotBrowser.Children.Add(_webBrowser);
        _webBrowser.Address = "http://www.google.com/";
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _webBrowser.ViewSourceCommand.Execute(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your using the latest release version (`43.0.1`) then use the `GetSourceAsync()` method.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/43/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L158

`ChromiumWebBrowser` implements the `IWebBrowser` interface so you can use the extension method if you just want the source for the main frame.

Comment: Yeah I got it yesterday. Managed to work it out but this is how I did it.